# Difference between two ways of designing loops

Tags: java, c++11, while-loop, coding-style

I was just wondering how does these different way of writing while loops could affect a code design.

> Can it have some differences in results in specific test cases ? 
>   what is generally suggested ? for a big chunk of code for simplicity.
>   In general anyone encountered issues in one of them and then corrected it by switching the way ?

```
While ( A && B)
{
  ...
  ...
}
```

and

```
While (A)
{
...
  While (B)
  {
   ...
  }
}
```

Comment: They're completely different things. The first has one loop, the second has two loops. You're comparing apples and airplanes here.

Answer (score 1):

To me they both are different

your first loop is single loop having two condition joined by `logical AND` which returns true in case of both of them are true

second one is nested loop.

### You asked

> Can it have some differences in results in specific test cases ?

well that depends on what inside the loop body but I haven't run into a case where these loops produces same results

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference in behaviour is the second one will stick in the outer loop when A is set but B is not.